# onClick em componentes criados dinamicamente React

Tags: javascript, onclick, react, react-dom

Possuo um componente `user-defined` chamado `<Match>` que é criado dinamicamente dentro de outro componente `<Event>`. Porém ao colocar onClick no componente  é estourado uma exceção. Como resolver o problema, sendo que para cada componente criado dinamicamente eu preciso de onClick que futuramente vai criar um novo componente.

> Events.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addBetCard' of
>   undefined(…)

#### Event.js

```
  createMatch (match) {
    return <Match source={match} key={match.id} onClick={this.addBetCard.bind(this)}/>;
  }

  createMatches (matches) {
    return matches.map(this.createMatch);
  }

render() {

   return(
   ...
      <div className="ListMatches">
      {this.createMatches(dataFake)}
      </div>
)}
```

#### Saída temporária, como melhorar?

Meu propósito é ter o onClick dentro do componente `<Match>` e toda vez que clicar no componente chamar onClick daquele componente.

```
addBetCard(item){
    console.log("Adicionando item");
  }

createMatch (match) {
    return <a key={match.id} onClick={this.addBetCard.bind(this, match)}><Match source={match}/></a>;
}

createMatches (matches) {
    return matches.map((i) => this.createMatch(i));
    // return matches.map(this.createMatch);
}

render() {

   return(
   ...
      <div className="ListMatches">
      {this.createMatches(dataFake)}
      </div>
)}
```

O trecho de código que eu coloquei logo acima resolve meu problema, de que quando clicar no componente chamar o método onClick dele. Porém é uma saída nada elegante onde eu preciso colocar o meu componente `<Match>` dentro de uma tag `<a>` que por sua vez, possui o onClick.

Comment: Falta o `=` e um `}` aí... deve ser `onClick={this.addBetCard.bind(this)}`

Comment: Falta ainda o `=`  depois do `onClick`... não vejo onde a variável `dataFake` é usada. O problema mantem-se ainda?

Comment: Valeu. Alguma sugestão de como resolver o problema?

Comment: Usa this.createMatches.call(this, dataFake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de corrigir os *"bindings"*, ou seja garantir que o contexto de execução é o correto.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.addBetCard = this.addBetCard.bind(this);
    this.createMatch = this.createMatch.bind(this);
    this.createMatches = this.createMatches.bind(this);
}

createMatch (match) {
    return <Match source={match} key={match.id} onClick={this.addBetCard}/>;
}

createMatches (matches) {
    return matches.map(this.createMatch);
}

render() {
     // const dataFake = ['etc', 'etc'];
     return (
          // ...
          <div className="ListMatches">
          {this.createMatches(dataFake)}
          </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente a solução que você passou não funcionou no meu caso. Consegui resolver mas a forma como resolvi to achando bem 'gambiarrosa'. Vou editar a pergunta acima pra vê se existe uma solução mais elegante.

Comment: @LuKsSys é dificil saber como o teu componente está. Podes adaptar este jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/paul_lecam/q2v7t59h/ com o teu componente para eu ver?

Comment: OK! vou fazer isso

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/q2v7t59h/255/. O objetivo é clicar em algum dos <h1> e apresentar um alerta ao clicar.

Comment: @LuKsSys ok, revi agora: https://jsfiddle.net/xwzfv7pc/ E o que queres mostrar no `console` quando houver `click`? o nome da equipa?

Comment: Justamente isso que preciso.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Por mim daria 2 up na sua resposta!!!